# Javascript: Edit Variable After Mapping Through Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement, iteration

I'm relatively new to programming and learning on my own, but I can't understand how to edit a variable by mapping through an array.

I have an array of all the best pies each with their own price:

```
[blueberry, strawberry, pumpkin, apple]
```

I want to the total to keep adding up based on the price using an if statement, something like:

```
    var total = 0
    arr.map(pie => {
    if (pie==="blueberry") {
    total = total + 2.5;}
    else if (pie === "apple") {
    total = total + 2}}
```

The thing is that the total goes up to 2.5, but then goes back to 0. So instead of 4.5 for this example, I get 2 because apple was the last pie to be added. :(

Why does this happen, and how can I make it so the total is saved and continues to add the other pies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
let arr = ['blueberry', 'strawberry', 'pumpkin', 'apple']
var total = 0

arr.forEach(pie => {
    if (pie==="blueberry") {
     total += 2.5;
    }
    else if (pie === "apple") {
     total += 2
    }
});

console.log(total)
```

Instead of applying `map` function, try to use `forEach` instead.

A simple explanation is as below:

[forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) — executes a provided function once for each array element.

[map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) — creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.

Comment: thanks Isaac :) Why does map not work to save the total?

Comment: I’d use reduce for this one. Have it return the total. Map does work but if you use it for this purpose, then it just shows us you don’t understand it’s purpose.

Comment: @jens: Yes of course, there are so many ways, `forEach` is definitely one of the many :)

Comment: @flored27: `Map` may not be appropriate but it should work too.

Comment: what if I wanted to create an array of objects that changes with total? like in this example have the result be [{total: 2.5},{total:4.5}]. would you need to use both map and foreach?

Comment: @flored27 In that case using `reduce` would be a much better call.

Comment: @jens: But I'm not using `map`?

Answer (score 0):

As Issac mentioned, it's generally considered bad form to use `map` for side effects (like updating an accumulator). That said, your example should work as given: see the snippet below.

```js
let arr = ['blueberry', 'strawberry', 'pumpkin', 'apple']
var total = 0

arr.map(pie => {
  if (pie==="blueberry") {
    total = total + 2.5;}
  else if (pie === "apple") {
    total = total + 2}
})

console.log(total)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your example still output `4.5`. But you should take a look [about API](https://developer.mozilla.org/vi/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) of `javascript` and get the simple meaning of it.

Here `map` is function which help you make another `array` from current `array`. In this case you can keep your code but just only change `.map()` to `.forEach()`.

```js
var arr = ['blueberry', 'strawberry', 'pumpkin', 'apple']
var totalMap = 0;
var totalForeach = 0;
arr.map(pie=>{
    if (pie === "blueberry") {
        totalMap = totalMap + 2.5;
    } else if (pie === "apple") {
        totalMap = totalMap + 2;
    }
});
arr.forEach(pie=>{
    if (pie === "blueberry") {
        totalForeach = totalForeach + 2.5;
    } else if (pie === "apple") {
        totalForeach = totalForeach + 2;
    }
});
console.log('map total:',totalMap);
console.log('forEach total:', totalForeach);
```